# What is the best way to use input boxes in tables in order to submit a form using Java?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I am trying to create a "workout planner" but I am struggling to come up with a smart way to actually code this.

Right now I am just using tables and having input boxes inside each  which I know is a terrible design since I need unique IDs for each input box.

How can I get the data from the input boxes without having to use unique IDs since I would also like the user to be able to add / remove rows from the table. This is a example of my table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDAIV.png

I have also attached a sample of my code. I believe that the way I coded it will not allow the user to add / remove rows since the ID has to be generated each time.

```
<tbody id="tbodyMonday">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondayExercise1" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondaySets1" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondayReps1" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondayRest1" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondayExercise2" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondaySets2" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondayReps2" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input class="workoutInputs" name="mondayRest2" type="text"/></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just using Microsoft Excel out of the question?  The way you have explained your idea makes me think this is for your own personal gym program. If this project is something you are building for the public (general Internet use) ... I mean, you are going to have to have some kind of backed "server" for your page to receive the data from your HTML input text fields.  You would need Java Servlets, or JSP or PHP or Node.js to receive your input data whenever a user wishes to add a row or column to a database.  The "code" you have posted is not really thought of as "code" since it's just the browser HTML that a user sees in his or her browser.  HTML by itself cannot really do anything.  You would need some programming code to do what you have asked about.

If you don't like MS Excel, a long time ago they would use MS Access - the simple database program for home users to save something as simple as a few workout and exercise 'rows' to a DB.

Again, **if your idea is for an Internet Web App or Android App, you will need to pick a server or backend technology. The browser doesn't allow HTML, JavaScript, and other client technologies to save database rows to a hard drive.**

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I'm not making my own personal gym program, I'm just making a quick little website to put on my resume.

I understand how to do the backend but I was just wondering is there a better way to do it instead of having a unique id for each row? If I do 6 exercises per day and work out 6 days a week, that is 36 unique IDs not including sets/reps/rest. I also want the user to be able to add / remove rows which I'm not sure is possible with this since a ID will have to be created each time somehow

Comment: Usually, in HTML, the convention is that ID's are unique - they should not be repeated in multiple HTML elements - but "class" attributes can be repeated.  This is just a convention - and since HTML is not compiled code - it cannot really crash, either.  You should read about CSS class attributes - if you want rows to repeat.  Anyway, last point, adding rows would require Java-Script...  ***But,*** adding rows and expecting these changes to be reflected ... ***in order to save your changes*** you would need backed software, like I mentioned...  JSP, or PHP, or Java, or Node.js, etc...